# Problema Trigger MySQL

Tags: mysql, trigger

estoy haciendo un ejercicio de triggers para clase y me he quedado algo pillado en este último porque me da error y no sé por qué. Os comento:

Tengo una base de datos con el siguiente esquema físico:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La idea del trigger es que se lance cada vez que se elimina un registro de la tabla Prestamo de tal forma que inserte en una tabla auxiliar que ya tengo creada el Id del cliente al cual pertenecía el préstamo y el número de préstamos que tiene aún en el banco.

El DDL utilizado en la base de datos es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE cliente
 (
   id CHAR(10) NOT NULL,
   nombre CHAR(50),
   calle CHAR(50),
   ciudad CHAR(50),
   PRIMARY KEY(id)
 );

CREATE TABLE cuenta
 (
  numero CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  saldo NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(numero)
  );

CREATE TABLE prestamo
 (
  numero CHAR(5) NOT NULL,
  cantidad NUMERIC(10,2) NOT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY(numero)
 );

CREATE TABLE impositor
 (
  id_cliente CHAR(10),
  numero_cuenta CHAR(5),
  PRIMARY KEY(id_cliente, numero_cuenta),
  FOREIGN KEY(id_cliente) 
  REFERENCES cliente(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
  FOREIGN KEY(numero_cuenta)
  REFERENCES cuenta(numero) ON DELETE CASCADE
 );

CREATE TABLE prestatario
(
 id_cliente CHAR(10),
 numero_prestamo CHAR(5),
 PRIMARY KEY(id_cliente, numero_prestamo),
 FOREIGN KEY(id_cliente) 
 REFERENCES cliente(id) ON DELETE CASCADE,
 FOREIGN KEY(numero_prestamo)
 REFERENCES prestamo(numero) ON DELETE CASCADE
 );
CREATE TABLE prueba
(
 id int not null auto_increment,
 usuario CHAR(10) not null,
 restantes int not null,
 PRIMARY KEY(id_cliente, numero_prestamo),
 FOREIGN KEY(id_cliente) 
);
```

Y el Trigger que tengo hecho hasta ahora es el siguiente:

```
DELIMITER // 
  CREATE TRIGGER addNewMessage AFTER DELETE ON prestamo
  FOR EACH ROW 

  BEGIN

   DECLARE usuario CHAR(10); #Creo las variables locales
   DECLARE prestamosRestantes INT; #Creo las variables locales

   #Hago las consultas que necesito e inserto el resultado de las mismas en las variables declaradas anteriormente
   SELECT prestatario.id_cliente INTO usuario FROM prestatario WHERE prestatario.numero_prestamo = OLD.numero; 
   SELECT COUNT(*) INTO prestamosRestantes FROM prestamo pr , prestatarioprest WHERE pr.numero = prest.numero_prestamo AND prest.id_cliente = usuario;

   #Inserto en la tabla auxiliar (prueba) el contenido de las variables anteriores 
   INSERT INTO prueba (usuario , restantes) values (usuario , prestamosRestantes);

  END //

DELIMITER ;
```

Y a la hora de que se lance el trigger cuando ejecuto un borrado en la tabla prestamo me arroja el siguiente error:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Creo que mi fallo está a la hora de asignar las variables dentro del trigger pero no sé como hacerlo, he probado a hacerlo con el **"SET usuario = (SELECT id_cliente FROM prestatario WHERE prestatario.numero_prestamo = OLD.numero);"**.

PD Las consultas que hago de SELECT y demás para obtener el valor que asignaré a mis variables funcionan bien y si las ejecuto de forma normal en la consola me dan el resultado esperado por eso creo que el fallo está a la hora de asignar ese resultado a la variable pero no se como va :(

Muchas gracias a todos.

**EDITO**

Tras ver lo que me han respondido y demás, me sigue dando el mismo error. La tabla prueba no contiene ningun Trigger ni nada por el estilo, el único trigger que hay es este que estoy creando. En este momento el código del trigger que tengo es el siguiente:

```
DELIMITER //
CREATE TRIGGER addNewMessage AFTER DELETE ON prestamo
FOR EACH ROW BEGIN

    DECLARE usuario CHAR(10);
    DECLARE prestamosRestantes INT;

    SET usuario = (SELECT prestatario.id_cliente FROM prestatario WHERE prestatario.numero_prestamo = OLD.numero LIMIT 1);
    SET prestamosRestantes = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM prestamo pr , prestatario prest WHERE pr.numero = prest.numero_prestamo AND prest.id_cliente = usuario);

    INSERT INTO prueba (usuario , restantes) values (usuario , prestamosRestantes);


END //
DELIMITER ;
```

Comment: No veo que estés usando `SET` como te indico en mi respuesta. Sigues con el `SELECT ... INTO`

Comment: Lo sientoo es que de tanto estar cambiando cosas ya no se ni cuál era el bueno y me he liado. Ya lo he editado y he puesto el que tiene que ser jejejeje

Comment: Revisa mi respuesta editada, he llevado el código a un escenario real y funciona. Había que crear un `TRIGGER` del tipo `BEFORE DELETE` y corregir algunas cosas en los `CREATE TABLE`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Cuando usas `SELECT ... INTO...` para asignar las variables dentro de un `TRIGGER` o de cualquiera otra función, MySQL se enfrenta a problemas de interpretación si las variables declaradas son nombres de columna de las tablas <sup>1</sup>. Tal práctica es por ese motivo [prohibida por el Manual de Referencia](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/local-variable-scope.html):

> A local variable should not have the same name as a table column. If
>   an SQL statement, such as a SELECT ... INTO statement, contains a
>   reference to a column and a declared local variable with the same
>   name, MySQL currently interprets the reference as the name of a
>   variable. Consider the following procedure definition:
>
> ---
>
> Una variable local no debe tener el mismo nombre que una columna de
>   tabla. Si una instrucción SQL, como una instrucción `SELECT ... INTO`,
>   contiene una referencia a una columna y una variable local declarada
>   con el mismo nombre, MySQL interpreta actualmente la referencia como
>   el nombre de una variable.

Para evitar tal confusión, el camino seguro es asignar los valores con `SET`.

Prueba de este modo:

```
   DECLARE usuario CHAR(10); #Creo las variables locales
   DECLARE prestamosRestantes INT; #Creo las variables locales

   #Hago las consultas que necesito e inserto el resultado de las mismas en las variables declaradas anteriormente
   SET usuario = (SELECT prestatario.id_cliente FROM prestatario WHERE prestatario.numero_prestamo = OLD.numero LIMIT 1); 
   SET prestamosRestantes = (SELECT COUNT(*) INTO prestamosRestantes FROM prestamo pr , prestatarioprest WHERE pr.numero = prest.numero_prestamo AND prest.id_cliente = usuario);

   #Inserto en la tabla auxiliar (prueba) el contenido de las variables anteriores 
   INSERT INTO prueba (usuario , restantes) values (usuario , prestamosRestantes);
```

He agregado un `LIMIT 1` a la primera asignación, porque siempre hay que evitar que ese tipo de consultas arroje más de una fila. Para la segunda no hace falta, dado que es un `COUNT`.

---

1. Para más detalles sobre esto puedes ver **[esta respuesta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/152353)** a la pregunta *MySQL select…into variable yields null, even though data is there* y también **[esta respuesta](https://dba.stackexchange.com/a/35207)**  a la pregunta *How do uninitialized variables differ from NULL in Mysql?*

---

### Otro problema con el `TRIGGER`

Aparte de lo dicho, el motivo por el que está encontrando un usuario nulo, es porque estás usando un `TRIGGER` del tipo `AFTER DELETE`, entonces, éste se lanza una vez el usuario ha sido borrado y como es lógico ya no lo encontrará, debes usar por tanto un `TRIGGER` del tipo `BEFORE DELETE`, para que tome el dato **antes de borrarlo** y lo guarde en la tabla `prueba`.

Aquí te dejo un ejemplo funcionando, he tenido que hacer varios ajustes, porque el código que presentas no me dejaba crear las tablas por varios errores, entre ellos, tu tabla `prueba` no es del todo correcta.

Este código funciona sin problemas, como puedes ver en los resultados:

**<kbd>[VER CÓDIGO EN REXTESTER](https://rextester.com/FYULU43359)</kbd>**

Comment: He cambiado los SELECT INTO variable por el SET variable = SELECT FROM .... y me sigue arrojando el error de la imagen que subí :(

Comment: @Josemanuu ¿Le pusiste `LIMIT 1` a la consulta como te indiqué? Al parecer la consulta arroja más de una fila y en ese caso el `SET` no funcionaría, por tanto debes escribirla así:  `SELECT prestatario.id_cliente FROM prestatario WHERE prestatario.numero_prestamo = OLD.numero LIMIT 1`

Comment: Si, le he puesto también el limit 1. El caso es que si la ejecuto a pelo si funciona pero al meterla en la variable es donde falla y no entiendo el porqué pero el fallo tiene que ser al asignar la variable

Comment: Es raro, debería funcionar así. ¿Si pruebas a poner un valor a mano dentro del `TRIGGER` funciona?, o sea, algo así: `INSERT INTO prueba (usuario , restantes) values ('Testzzz' , prestamosRestantes);`

Comment: Lo he probado y si que me inserta el nombre que he puesto a pelo pero el restantes me lo pone como 0 en plan de que en lugar de añadir el contenido de la variable de prestamosRestantes me ha metido un 0 que es el valor que mete por default cuando el campo es null.

Conclusión: El fallo está al asignar las variables pero no veo donde. Seguro que es una tontería pero joe el por culo que esta dando :/

Comment: Una pregunta, ¿tienes `TRIGGER` declarados para la tabla `prueba` también? Los `SET` generalmente funcionan del modo que te he indicado. ¿Podrías editar tu pregunta, poniendo al final de la misma cómo tienes el código actualmente?

Comment: Nop, no tengo ningun trigger sobre esa tabla. En cuanto al código está igual que antes. Estoy haciendo pruebas a parte cambiando lo del SELECT y poniendo un SET y demás pero bueno, ahora lo pongo

Comment: @Josemanuu revisa mi respuesta, la edición que he agregado al final y el enlace de prueba en rextester. Con eso debería resolverse tu problema. Tu tabla `prueba` tampoco era del todo correcta. En la prueba que he hecho modificando algunas cosas funciona.

Comment: Ya esta solucionado!! El problema es que la tabla tiene la foreign key como delete on cascade entonces al lanzar el trigger después de que borre, ya no hay forma de encontrar ese usuario y por tanto da null y salta el error. Todo solucionado lanzando el trigger antes de borrar jjejeje