# ¿Cómo eliminar datos eliminados de una tabla y guardalos en otra con php & mysql?

Tags: php, mysql

Estoy trabajando con una base datos y `php` y me gustaría poder eliminar datos de una tabla y guardarlos en otra, de esta forma esos datos no los pierdo, porque los necesito, pero si que los quito de la vista del usuario.

Este es el código que muestra los datos en una tabla al usuario. Y puede eliminar y editar, pero cuando pincha en guardar, quisiera que esos datos se fuesen a otra tabla de la BBDD y se quitasen de esa tabla y por tanto de la vista del usuario. Espero que me podáis ayudar:

```
<p>Resultados <?php echo $datos->num_rows; ?></p>
<div class="row table-responsive">
<table class="display" id="mitabla" border="1"  style="width:100%" >

<thead style='background-color:#292929;'>

    <th align="center"><font color=#FFFFFF>Marcar</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>N&#186; Cliente</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Nombre completo</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Zona de Ventas</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Ramo Inicial</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Ramo Definitivo</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Tipo Contrato</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Fecha Env&#237;o</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Fecha Recepci&#243;n</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Contador &#40;Fechas&#41;</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Comentarios </th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Anexo Contrato</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Escalado Distrib.</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>&#37; Bonus Distrib.</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Factur Anual Distrib.</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Anotaciones Internas</th>
    <th align="left"><font color=#FFFFFF>Anexo Interno</th>
    <th align="center"><font color=#FFFFFF>Editar</th>
    <th align="center"><font color=#FFFFFF>Borrar</th>
    <th align="center"><font color=#FFFFFF>Guardar</th>

</thead>

<?php while($d= $datos->fetch_object()):?>


    <tr>
    <td align="center"><input type="checkbox" name="casilla[]" value="<?php echo $d->id_contrpen; ?>"class="check"></td>

    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->noCliente; ?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->nombreCliente;?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->zv; ?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->ramo; ?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->ramoDef; ?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->tipoContr ; ?></td>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $d->fechaEnvio; ?></td>
    <td align="right"><?php echo $d->fechaRecep; ?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->contador; ?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->comentarios; ?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->anexo; ?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->anexoDistrEscal; ?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->anexoDistrBonus; ?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->anexoDistrFact; ?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->anotaciones; ?></td>
    <td align="left"><?php echo $d->anexoInter; ?></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="modificarContrPend.php?id_contrpen=<?php echo $d-> id_contrpen; ?>"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-pencil"></span></a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="#" data-href="eliminarContrPend.php?id_contrpen=<?php echo $d->id_contrpen; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td>
    <td align="center"><a href="guardarContrPendBackup.php?id_contrpen=<?php echo $d->id_contrpen; ?>" ><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-floppy-disk"></span></a></td>
    </tr>

<?php endwhile; ?>
```

```
    <?php else:?>
    <h3>No hay Datos</h3>
    <?php endif; ?>
```

Gracias de antemano a todos.

Este es el trigger

DROP TRIGGER IF EXISTS `Contratos_Pendientes_Backup`;CREATE DEFINER=`cpses_djt2tjlsec`@`localhost` TRIGGER `Contratos_Pendientes_Backup` BEFORE DELETE ON `contratospendientes` FOR EACH ROW INSERT INTO contratospendientesBackup (`id_contrpen`, `noCliente`, `nombreCliente`, `zv`, `ramo`, `ramoDef`, `tipoContr`, `fechaEnvio`, `fechaRecep`, `contador`, `comentarios`, `anexo`, `anexoDistrEscal`, `anexoDistrBonus`, `anexoDistrFact`, `anotaciones`, `anexoInter`, `created_at`) VALUES (`contratospendientes.noCliente`, `contratospendientes.nombreCliente`, `contratospendientes.zv`, `contratospendientes.ramo`, `contratospendientes.ramoDef`, `contratospendientes.tipoContr`, `contratospendientes.fechaEnvio`, `contratospendientes.fechaRecep`, `contratospendientes.contador`, `contratospendientes.comentarios`, `contratospendientes.anexo`, `contratospendientes.anexoDistrEscal`, `contratospendientes.anexoDistrBonus`, `contratospendientes.anexoDistrFact`, `contratospendientes.anotaciones`, `contratospendientes.anexoInter`)

[image: Configuración del Trigger]

Comment: Un consejo cuando quieres "borrar" datos, utiliza un campo de tu tabla que sea un 1-0 true-false, etc... Y que dependiendo del valor los muestres en el select o no. De esta manera, con un update sobre la tabla sería suficiente para ocultar los registros que no quieres mostrar

Comment: Una forma muy común es tener una columna "activo" o similar con un valor true/false o 0/1. Cuando creas un cliente, lo creas con activo=true. Y cuando lo borras en vez de hacer un delete de la fila, haces un update y pones activo=false. Cuando obtienes una lista de clientes, solo buscas los que tengan activo a true. Si necesitas copiarlo a otra tabla, tendrás que preguntarte en qué momento? en la inserción, en el borrado, en diferentes intervalos...

Comment: @ordago bueno, creo que estamos exactamente de acuerdo jajaja

Comment: No hace falta que te rompas la cabeza programando esto en PHP. Las BD permiten programar disparadores o TRIGGER para casos como estos. Puedes por tanto programar uno del tipo BEFORE DELETE que inserte en la tabla de resguardo el registro antes de borrarlo. Al final de [esta respuesta](https://es.stackoverflow.com/a/258238/29967) hay un enlace a una demo sobre esto mismo. Es el camino a seguir si efectivamente lo que quieres es borrar el registro porque **no lo necesitas más en esa tabla**. Si es una cuestión de vistas simplemente es mejor que modifiques la lógica de tu programa y no la tabla.

Comment: Muchas gracias por vuestras respuestas. Lo que necesito es lo que A.Cedano comenta, borrar el dato de una tabla y que envíe a otra para no perderlo. He editado mi pregunta para poner el Trigger que configurado con BEFORE DELETE, Lo que pasa que me pasa los datos vacíos a la otra tabla. Y no se por qué.

Answer (score 2):

Te recomiendo que hagas un trigger donde copias el registro que estés por borrar, el trigger trabaja directamente desde la base de datos, y evita que tengas que preocuparte tu, por estar grabando antes de borrar, ya que lo hace de forma automática.

Utilizo el Heidi SQL para administrar las bases de datos, y es muy sencillo configurar los triggers desde allí, aunque igual te dejo links donde encontraras mas información.

una vez que configuras el trigger el código es muy sencillo porque básicamente es la copia de un registro de una tabla a otra, también te anexo el código.

PD. Recuerda que ambas tablas deben tener la mismas estructura.

```
INSERT INTO registroProduccionB
(id,fechaReg,usuario,area,linea,turno,fecha1)
VALUES
(OLD.id,OLD.fechaReg,OLD.usuario,OLD.area,OLD.linea,OLD.turno,OLD.fecha1)
```

[image: Ejemplo de Trigger antes de borrar]

[Más información](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/trigger-syntax.html)

Comment: Gracias Oswaldo por tu respuesta. He creado un Trigger. Tengo la tabla origen "contratospendientes" y la tabla a la que quiero copiar lo que elimino. El Trigger lo he creado en la de origen, para que BEFORE DELETe, lleve los datos de la tabla a la otra. Pues cuando ejecuto  <td align="center"><a href="#" data-href="eliminarContrPend.php?id_contrpen=<?php echo $d->id_contrpen; ?>" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#confirm-delete"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span></a></td> Me borra los datos de la tabla de origen pero a la otra llegan en blanco. Me puedes ayudar?

Comment: Claro, me puedes mostrar el codigo de tu trigger.

Comment: @Monica por favor, incluye el código de tu trigger en la pregunta, editándola

Comment: Ok. Lo he añadido

Comment: Hola @Oswaldo, no se si has podido mirar el código. Disculpa que te vuelva a preguntar, pero no se donde puede estar el error. No me lleva los datos a la tabla de backup. Muchas gracias de antemano por tu ayuda.

Comment: Hola Monica, disculpa la demora, según veo no tienes los mismos campos, mira el primero de tu insert es "id_contrpen" y el primero de tu value es "contratospendientes.noCliente" es decir que estas saltandote el primer campo, revisa que para cada insert exista un value, y que el tipo de dato también sea igual.

Comment: Hola Oswaldo. Ya he solucionado el paso de los datos de una tabla a otra y que se borren de la primera. AL final no lo he hecho con un Trigger si no con código PHP. Agradezco mucho tu ayuda